extending recursive find to .tar, tar.gz, tar.bz2, and tar.xz on Debian 12
Continuing find a file within a tar.gz archive, how is it possible to automatically recursively search for files with given names, including the files inside the archives and compressed archives?
For example, if foo.tar.gz, dir1/bar.tar.bz2, dir2/dir3/foobar.tar.xz, and dir4/dir5/dir6/barfoo.tar are in the current directory, then
deepfind . -iname baz

(I made the name deepfind up) should look for the file named baz (in arbitrary case) not only in the usual directory structure below . but also in the contents of the four (compressed or plain) aforementioned tar archives.
Our system is Debian 12, so that nobody attempts to suggest or even mention obsolete, uninstallable, or unusable software.

Does this answer your question? Find recursively all archive files of diverse archive formats and search them for file name patterns

@arielmarcovitch In the question you cited, the original poster does NOT ask for the files to be looked for in the usual directory structure. In this question, on the contrary, we do.

@AlMa1r That seems to be a trivial extension: just run a find . -iname baz after the commands in the other question? Or, if you understand the find command in the second answer, just add -o -iname baz

@muru Of course I understand this. Although that you said seems (or is) easy, there is, technically speaking, no answer suggesting exactly what you said. So feel free to provide an answer here and collect reputation points, orelse I'd consider doing this.

Given a tar archive, like archive.tar, you could use
tar -t -f archive.tar | grep -e 'pattern'

... to look for pattern (some regular expression) in the table of contents of the archive.  If the archive is compressed, you may either let tar uncompress the archive for you (if it is able to do so, depending on the compressor used and the tar implementation at hand), or you may decompress it separately, e.g.,
gzip -d -c archive.tar.gz | tar -t -f - | grep -e 'pattern'

If the compressor is not known, you may use a case statement to pick the correct one based on the archive's filename suffix. A tar-toc script may therefore look something like this:
#!/bin/sh

archive=$1

cat "$archive" |
case $archive in
        *.tar)          cat             ;;
        *.tar.gz)       gzip -d -c      ;;
        *.tar.bz2)      bzip2 -d -c     ;;
        *.tar.xz)       xz -d -c        ;;
        *)
                echo 'Unknown compressor' >&2
                cat >/dev/null
esac |
tar -t -f -

... or using if-then-else-etc. in bash:
#!/bin/bash

archive=$1

cat "$archive" |
if [[ $archive == *.tar ]];             then cat
elif [[ $archive == *.tar.gz ]];        then gzip -d -c
elif [[ $archive == *.tar.bz2 ]];       then bzip2 -d -c
elif [[ $archive == *.tar.xz ]];        then xz -d -c
else
        echo 'Unknown compressor' >&2
        cat >/dev/null
fi |
tar -t -f -

This would be used to find all file paths matching some pattern in a possibly compressed tar archive like so (this looks for pathnames ending in .sh):
$ ./tar-toc ~/archives/project.tar.xz | grep '\.sh$'

You may then combine this with find to look for archives that contain files with pathnames matching a particular pattern:
find /some/path \( \
        -name '*.tar' -o \
        -name '*.tar.gz' -o \
        -name '*.tar.bz2' -o \
        -name '*.tar.xz' \
    \) -type f \
    -exec ./tar-toc {} \; | grep -e 'pattern'

This would list all matching pathnames in all found tar archives.  To instead output the names of the archives that contain the matching files:
find /some/path \( \
        -name '*.tar' -o \
        -name '*.tar.gz' -o \
        -name '*.tar.bz2' -o \
        -name '*.tar.xz' \
    \) -type f \
    -exec sh -c './tar-toc "$1" | grep -q -e "$2"' sh {} 'pattern' \; \
    -print

This uses -exec to start an inline sh -c script which runs our tar-toc script on the found tar archive.  The inline script also uses grep -q to determine if the table of contents matches the given regular expression.  If grep -q find something, it will exit with a zero exit status, signalling success, which will cause find to print the pathname of the tar archive using -print.

Take a look at zfind:
zfind 'name ilike "baz"'

Searches inside archives and supports all formats you mentioned.
